# Issue kubecfg applying kube-state-metrics

Tags: kubernetes, observability

I'm trying to apply kube-state-metrics by running on devbox:

```
kubecfg apply -f kube-config/kube-state-metrics/kube-state-metrics.jsonnet --context dev-azure-westeuropec2
```

but I am getting this error that a file is missing:

```
sjsonnet.Error: Couldn't import file: "kube-config/kube-state-metrics/zzz-servicecfg-output/index.jsonnet"
```

Comment: PLease share contents of `kube-state-metrics.jsonnet`

Comment: [kubecfg](https://github.com/kubecfg/kubecfg) doesn't have an apply command.  What tool are you using?